# AttributeError 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python

I'm managing an api and I would like to understand why I have the error "AttributeError 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'"

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


incidents = []
limit = 100
offset = 0
got_all_events = False
while not got_all_events:
    alerts = requests.get(f'***', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('***', '***'))
    print(alerts)
    for alert in alerts:
        incident = { 
            'name': alert.get('hostname'),
            'rawJSON': json.dumps(alert),
        }
        incidents.append(incident)
    if len(alerts) == limit:
        offset += limit
    else:
        got_all_events = True

print(incident)
```

The error is regarding this code line

```
'name': alert.get('hostname'),
```

From my api my array is defined like that:

```
{
  "totalSize": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "hostname": "string",
      "domain": "string",
      "tags": "string",
      "os": {},

    }
  ],
  "size": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary has the `hostname` key nested in a subdictionary as part of a list, so the get is unable to find it.

The only valid targets for the get on alert are `totalsize`, `data`, and `size`.

You could run a get on alert with key `data` to return a list, then run another get on position 0 of that list with key `hostname` to get what you want.

A more straightforward approach would just be:

```
'name': alert["data"][0]["hostname"]
```

Comment: `alert` doesn't have any keys, because it's not a `dict` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`alerts` is a `requests.Response` object, not something decoded from JSON. You have to extract the body first. The *iterator* for a `Response` yields a sequence of `bytes` values, which is where the `bytes` value you think should be a `dict` comes from.

```
response = requests.get(f'***', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('***', '***'))

alerts = response.json()

for alert in alerts:
    incident = { 
        'name': alert.get('hostname'),
        'rawJSON': json.dumps(alert),
    }
    incidents.append(incident)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

Now it is working like that:

```
 r=alerts.json()
    for alert in r['data']:
        incident = { 
             'hostName': alert["hostname"],             
        }
        incidents.append(incident)

print(json.dumps(incidents, indent=1))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).